# What is the specification of the extra screws needed to install a second drive to an upper-drive populated Mac Mini 2012?

Tags: hard-drive, mac-mini

I ordered the [wrong OWC Data Doubler kit](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other+World+Computing/DIYIMM11D2/). I didn't notice the note saying that some Mac Minis have an upper drive configuration and that it would require a [variant of the kit with additional components](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DIYIMM11D2B/). The additional items in the variant are the **5mm wrench** and **2 set screws**. I considered exchanging the item but the local shop that imported the item is charging me for the return. Does anybody know the specification of the additional screws that I need? There's a similar question I found here [Can the 2011 Mac-Mini (not the Server Edition) Support an Additional Hardisk, SSD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/can-the-2011-mac-mini-not-the-server-edition-support-an-additional-hardisk-ss). But it's unclear whether the ifixit kit mentioned here is for the lower drive config or upper drive config Mac Mini.

Comment: do you have a place near by for computers dump? check it out.

Answer (score 1):

According to [iFixit's HD replacement guide for Mac Mini 2012](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Mini+Late+2012+Hard+Drive+Replacement/11716), you need *both* a T6 Torx screwdriver and a T8 Torx screwdriver. The guide shows the corresponding screw specifications for each relevant step (IE two 6.6 mm T8 Torx screws), but iFixit only sells the screwdrivers, not the screws themselves AFAIK. *They do, however, supply you with the information needed regarding all the relevant screws.*

Comment: You're welcome. Notice on the right hand pane of the iFixit guide each step includes a description of the circled pieces. Print out the guide and just highlight the relevant pieces needed. Then head over to the hardware store :)

Comment: Additionally, see [Mac Mini Dual Drive Kit](http://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/Mac-Mini-Dual-Drive-Kit/IF171-005)

Comment: This [video](http://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/mac_mini2012_dd2_m/) shows the peg used at the 4:28 mark. I now have a better idea of what to ask the local hardware.

Comment: I also found ifixit's dual hard drive installation instructions [here](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+Mac+Mini+Late+2012+Dual+Hard+Drive+Kit/11713#s28339), which also shows the set screws used. Unfortunately, this guide is not as detailed in the spec of the screws used as the replacement guide **njboot** linked. But I think the "headless screws 8mm M3 with a 0.5mm thread" mentioned [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/can-the-2011-mac-mini-not-the-server-edition-support-an-additional-hardisk-ss) is probably what I am looking for.